# How to do getter with parameter using vuex-module-decorators?

Tags: vuex, getter, vuex-module-decorators

I'm trying to implement a vuex getter function (with parameter) using the Typescript/ES7 *Decorators* provided by *vuex-module-decorators*.

the normal vuex implementation would look like this:

```js
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        students: []
    },
    getters: {
        findStudent: state => id => state.students.find(s => s.id == id)
    }
})
```

The vuex-module-decorators [style guide](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-module-decorators#automatic-getter-detection) says to use Typescript getter accessor

```
@Module
class MyModule extends VuexModule {
  students = []

  get findStudent(id) {
    return students.find(s => s.id == id)
  }
}
```

Therefor, of course my linter complains `A 'get' accessor cannot have parameters`

What would then be the best practice to implement such getter? Or should do the logic of such function into my vue component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [github](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-module-decorators/issues/40)

Return a function from the getter

```
get getUser() { return function (id: string) { /* ... */ } }
```

Comment: thanks :-) I must have missed that issue